Someone in management has hinted that I need to bail fast. Should I?
Recently a manager, a close friend of the family, but not my direct chain of command has insinuated that things aren't pretty in the workplace and that layoffs are coming down the pipeline.
I hadn't heard anything until he mentioned it (or rather "Couldn't say") and added to that fact is that my direct supervisor has just randomly quit for his own mental health.
It could just be coincidence and I'm not sure how to take it, but I trust this manager to be truthful with me, even in "What he CAN'T say") but he did imply I should get a lifeboat and fast.
Should I?

It's really hard to answer. What do you mean by bailing - quitting, looking for a new job, or something else? Could you stay and look for a job? How easy are jobs in your field to get? How happy are you working there? Do you want a new job? Would you be entitled to redundancy payments if you were laid off? (Note that there are pros and cons to waiting till after you're redundant before job-hunting, especially if it will take up a lot of your time, but no harm in looking.)

Before you put in your notice you need to go looking for a different job, that way if layoff does happen, you would have already started the process of finding a different job.

This depends on what field you are in, how easy it is to find another job, and if you would need to relocate for a new job.

Since this question involves making a choice, I cannot answer the question.  But when making any choice, collecting more information can greatly inform your decision.  Did the company lose a major contract?  Is the company hiring for positions that match your current job (thus indicating the company is growing and not laying off)?  Did the company publish a quarterly earning report that looked bleak?

@stuartf Yes, quitting then looking for a new job, I could stay and look, but the implications I understood was to "get out, get out now", jobs are really tough at the moment in my industry and I am happy here, I don't specifically "want" to change jobs, but I realise it may not be up to me. As for redundancy, I have 2 months to go before I'm eligible (stupid 2 year laws)

@anketam I'm not sure. As far as I'm aware of, the company is in profit and hasn't lost any kind of contract, but no new jobs are hiring and as previously stated, this manager is trustworthy and he's fairly high up so has more knowledge than I do

People can be wrong, or may embellish. I've heard this before, without the doom arriving.

@Raisus - If you can afford to quit a job without another job already lined up, then you can of course go that route, but it seems short sighted to leave literal money on the table.

@MichaelMcFarlane And even if your informant's correct about the company situation, they may not correctly predict its effect on you.  You might find yourself redundant soon; or you might find you're valued enough to keep.  And in the latter case, the company might end up folding anyway, or it might recover and leave you in a very good position.  (I've seen all those.)  It's hard to predict, and impossible to generalise.  All you can do is to be prepared (as per the answers).

He risked his own trustability in the circle of the other managers to warn you. No ordinary mortal gets such a grace in his entire life. You are now obliged by all existing moral laws to not discern him in any case, in any context, for no one.

There is nothing wrong with taking preliminary steps:

Update your resume.
Get a feel for the market and what employers are looking for.
Can you leverage this into a promotion?
What skills or education do you need to brush up on to get that next promotion/position?
Apply for some interesting jobs.

Doing those kinds of things puts you "ahead of the pack" if layoffs do happen.  If they don't no harm.
Also you may want to just change jobs because a better opportunity presents itself.
There is no reason to quit now, but there is reason to take action.


Should I?

Should you what?

Update your resume? Yes.
Refresh your professional network? Yes.
Prepare financially as if you will be laid off? Yes.
Quit without having another job lined up? No.

Many years ago things didn't look good in my company. I started preparing and interviewing. When the layoffs happened, I already had a job offer in hand.
I ended up with a decent chunk of change as a severance package and moved right into a new job with an increase in pay and no time out of work.
Just be prepared.

At some level, points 1 through 3 should be a continual effort for just about anyone.

@JonCuster While it is good to do these first few steps periodically, the warning is a sign to do them now.

There are two excellent answers about the prudent steps one should take to protect yourself.
However, I want to address a slightly different aspect of this question:
I am not familiar with the minutiae of UK law - but I would imagine that things like Layoffs and executive decisions come with all sorts of confidentiality and protections.
Someone blabbing to a 3rd party source (such as the Media or colleagues etc.) would likely find themselves in a world of trouble (whether that be just at the company or actual legal trouble).
And so when it comes to evaluating Information - the greater the risk to the individual who is providing it, the more likely it is that one should consider it.
To use a very hyperbolic example - imagine if Person A could be sentenced to death for telling Person B some bit of information.
Clearly Person A views that the sharing of this information to be of such critical importance that they are risking their life.
Now, to tone it down to reality for a bit - your family friend is probably risking a lot of legal trouble or career suicide by telling you (as you might tell someone else, who might tell someone else etc.) and as such - I would heed the warning(s) - which brings us to the fantastic two answers already given.

As a corollary: you should seriously consider keeping your friend's confidence, and not letting on that they have told you, in order to protect them.
